# join the imported numbers Python

Tags: python, list, join

How can I join this list of numbers [1,131.15] ?

(imported data is a stock price which is "1,131.15" )

```
page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=GOOG")
text = page.read().decode("utf8")

where = text.find('l84_goog">')
start_of_price = where + 10
end_of_price = start_of_price + 8
```

Comment: What do you want your result to look like. Please include in your answer

Comment: What do you exactly want ?

Comment: What do you mean "join"? You mean make a string out of it or sum it or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to throw away the commas and then convert the string to a `float` value if you need numeric computations

```
final_num = float(list_of_numbers.replace(",", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
num_list = [1,131.15]
final_num = float(''.join([str(i) for i in num_list]))

>>> final_num
1131.15
```

Comment: i want just to make the price 1131.15 without a comma

Comment: @user3467282, Had to make some changes. Changed again